# How to determine loop-level parallelism dependence on a future iteration of a previous statement?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, dependencies

If a statement (S1) is dependent on a previous statement's (S0) FUTURE iteration, is that considered true dependence because S0 comes before S1, or anti-dependence because i+1 (S1) comes after i (S0)?

Consider this loop:

```
for (i=1; i<=N; i++) {
  for (j=N; j>=i; j--­­) {
       MatrixY[i][j] = blah_blah_irrelevant_for_question; //S0
       MatrixZ[i][j] = MatrixY[i­+1][j-1]; //S1
}
}
```

Can we write:

```
S0[i, j] ->T S1[i-1, j+1]
```

Or do we have to write:

```
S0[i, j] ->T S1[i, j+1]  AND S0[i, j] ->A S1[i-1,j]
```

At first I thought the former but now I think the latter.

Answer (score 1):

It is an anti-dependency.

The alternative term "write after read" dependency is more helpful here.  Statement S1 reads and uses the value of (to it) `MatrixY[i­+1][j-1]`.  The value of that object is later written by an execution of statement S0, which is the write after the read.  If the relative execution order of those two operations -- one read and one write of the same location -- were changed, then the computation would produce a different, presumably undesired result.

Note also that this brings out a subtlety: dependencies such as these are not so much between statements generally, but rather between specific executions of them.  Sometimes that distinction is immaterial, but yours is not such a case.

How you express the dependency depends on the formalism you are using.

Comment: I believe it is actually anti dependence on the j loop too? (j-1) Because j is iterating backwards (j--), so there aren't any true dependencies here at all, actually?

Comment: @whoami, that `j` is iterating backward is of no importance in the particular circumstances presented in the question.  With respect only to what is presented, the inner loop could be run forward instead of backward without changing the result of (serial execution of) the code presented.